# get server ip in java (Struts)

Tags: java, tomcat, struts

i want to get ip server where my tomcat is execute in java (Struts).?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()

Comment: not work when i execute since my server tomcat i've got this adresse 127.0.0.1 or is wrong

Comment: I do this and work for me:
<code>
String ipServer = "";
ipServer = request.getServerName();
</code>